# Geoprocessing Failed Error?

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service

Currently, I am having some problems with ArcGIS Online custom Geoprocessing tools.

I made a custom tool using ModelBuilder and published it on my portal. Even though they worked just fine with no problem whatsoever in ArcGIS Desktop, they seem to give out an error when running in Online.

The error is nothing more than "failed" and i was wondering if anybody knows **how to get more details of what went wrong** so I can try to fix I?

Currently I have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good tool to have in your arsenal is the Developer console. In your browser, open it by pushing CTRL+SHIFT+I (I will be describing this in Chrome, Firefox is very similar). 
Switch to the Network Tab and have your app ready to execute the GP tool. Now click the clear button in the console[image: Clear Button], this should clear out the window for you so you can see what happens after you execute the tool.

Now run your tool and wait for the error to appear. You will see a number of new items appear in the network tab. Switch to the Preview tab within Network (Response in Firefox) and click your way through the items one by one, your error will probably be one of the last items in the list. Somewhere on there will often be a more detailed error message, if the tool returned one, or at least some other hints as to what's going on (connection problems, for example).
Here is an example of an error returned by a sample GP tool from ESRI (note that I had to click the arrow next to messages to expand the list):

[image: Example of error shown in developer console.]

Answer (score 3):

When you publish a geoprocess on ArcGIS server, you can specify notifications level (see photo). This will give you more info than just error.

[image]